# Strange behavior with table td padding CSS

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-tables

If I apply a TD padding with the following CSS:

```
#maincontent table td, #maincontent table th {
    padding: .333em 0 .333em .25em;
}
```

… in Safari and IE the padding is applied to the TD as it should — BUT NOT on Firefox.

If I apply the TD-padding in the CSS only to the TD — and not the th — the padding is not set in all Browsers:

```
#maincontent table td {
    padding: .333em 0 .333em .25em;
}
```

AND if I change the order of the td/th, it does also not work (in all browsers):

```
#maincontent table th, #maincontent table td {
    padding: .333em 0 .333em .25em;
}
```

Why does this behave that strange!? … I do not set anything else to the table (only a `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` css-reset) and a 100% width and 1em-margin to the table-element itself. But nothing else on td, th, tr, tbody or something else in the table.

Comment: it's always nice to show a working example, using www.jsbin.com or www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not it works — as if by an invisible hand…

I guess it was a corrupt character…